# Using generic types in Flow

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I'm having trouble getting a utility function that uses generic types to pass Flow's type-checking. The same function passes in TypeScript, which has left me scratching my head as to why Flow doesn't seem to comprehend the function the way TypeScript does. Can anyone shed some light on what I can do to get Flow to parse this code properly?

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Dict%3Ca%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20a%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Case%3Ca%2C%20b%3E%20%3D%20(a)%20%3D%3E%20b%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Cases%3Ca%2C%20b%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09defaultCase%3A%20Case%3Ca%2C%20b%3E%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20Dict%3CCase%3Ca%2C%20b%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20caseOf%20%3D%20%3Ca%2C%20b%3E(cases%3A%20Cases%3Ca%2C%20b%3E)%20%3D%3E%20(someCaseFrom%3A%20(a)%20%3D%3E%20string)%20%3D%3E%20(value%3A%20a)%3A%20b%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!cases.hasOwnProperty('defaultCase'))%20throw%20new%20TypeError('Expected%20cases%20to%20include%20a%20default%20case%2C%20but%20none%20was%20provided.')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20someCase%3A%20string%20%3D%20someCaseFrom(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20cases.hasOwnProperty(someCase)%20%3F%20cases%5BsomeCase%5D(value)%20%3A%20cases.defaultCase(value)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0AcaseOf%3C%7B%20position%3A%20string%20%7D%2C%20string%3E(%7B%0D%0A%09first%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'first'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20second%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'second'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20third%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'third'%2C%0D%0A%09defaultCase%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'other'%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A((value%3A%20%7B%20position%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20value.position)%0D%0A(%7B%20position%3A%20'first'%20%7D))

[Try Flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AEQJYDGKAPAIYB8oAvKAN6gDaA1lmgFygDOKATvgDsA5gF1OZUAF9k6bKADCZLlnIAaUACMqtABRkAlDSoaA3DMw5Fyrms3b6iAJAATLJDIBXaCitZOv2y1ESVAAMjwiUgCydS0KM0RCWAEeUEIlLAB5SBpQQIoddOt-DJsYu0NqKh0uWABbLF8AMV56zj1Kqh5+YU7QHQA3MmgPP1ADTg0jB1BZ0HwcnQBCIqwuADoACyVM+AEABVbsXnQdAHJXdy8fDLP9QxRN1vhQASwXgBULAFFeVt5zt8AB7YYhYZxpUqgFCweYCQgjVzjUCXTzeSHKWIeFCvZI4eBKUAYVoDfCuZzrO4JOZpZKpWoNXycbqCIS5BmNDIteqDYajfRmGm8LAoDy8AQYtZbHZ7Q6wY6nDm+QwAfklXEYSoyIl5Iywhk4qw2qOuvl1-LMkkFNLmiQy2RIDAwsC4+BQ+GSzL4rKk6hZwgKdCckHwvB47T6ZxDYZQZ1UiBpyiSAmcEemZyTyWccYTc0eodT-Uj+d42fjLjcaJuyjTVVAZ1gjywvDOwX0iB05rGTpdbo9Ai9PTZkj6Qz162drvdyXbOh7U-7nCjoZ4Zyk7aAA)

Comment: It looks good to me. I asked someone from the flow community to have a look. If no response perhaps open a ticket on github if there is no way around it.

Comment: Thanks, I've opened a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6508).